# GNU make: check whether a python module needs to be installed

Tags: python, gnu-make

I'm using GNU make on Ubuntu bionic, and I need to check whether I need to install an Ubuntu python package with `apt-get`.

I tried this in my `Makefile` to capture the python import error (`ModuleNotFoundError`):

```
MY_PYTHON     := $(shell echo `which python3`)
MY_SETUPTOOLS := $(shell $(MY_PYTHON) -c 'import setuptools' )

ifneq ($(findstring /python3,$(MY_PYTHON)),/python3)
$(info 1. Installing python)
TMP := $(shell apt-get -y install python python3)
MY_PYTHON := $(shell echo `which python3`)
endif

ifeq ($(findstring ModuleNotFoundError,$(MY_SETUPTOOLS)),ModuleNotFoundError)
$(info 1. Installing setuptools)
TMP := $(shell apt-get -y install python-setuptools python3-setuptools)
endif

.PHONY: test
test:
        cd $(THIS_DIR); cd tests; py.test -s test_mytools.py
        make clean
```

I see the error below printed to the terminal when I run `sudo make test`; but it doesn't trigger the logic to install `python3-setuptools` with `apt-get`:

```
$ sudo make test
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/mpennington/foo'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

How can I fix this so `make` installs `python3-setuptools`?

Comment: Why write `$(shell echo \`which python3\`)` instead of just `$(shell which python3)`?  Although actually `which` is not a standard utility and more portable way would be `$(shell command -v python3)`

Comment: @MadScientist, `$(shell command -v python3)` throws an error when I tried it: `make: command: Command not found`

Comment: heh.  you must have a version of GNU make pre 4.3, that doesn't realize `command` is a shell built-in.  You can force it by adding a semicolon like: `$(shell command -v python3;)`

Comment: I've got GNU make from Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic); `$(shell command -v python3;)` worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was to redirect stderr to stdout when I checked for `python3-setuptools`:

```
MY_SETUPTOOLS := $(shell $(MY_PYTHON) -c 'import setuptools' 2>&1 )
                                                             ^^^^
```